# Blessed Solanus Casey---Prophecy Regarding Disappearance of Large Portions of the United States Due to Flooding?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, prophecy, united-states, beatification

Some number of years ago, I recall having seen (I am sure it was on television and I believe it was in the 1990s) a documentary (I would like to say it was a show called "Unsolved Mysteries," but I am not sure)---on a prophecy regarding the future reshaping of the map of the United States due to some kind of massive flooding. I don't recall if this flooding was to supposed to occur gradually or quickly.

I further recall that it was a prophecy of the recently beatified, Solanus Casey.

However, over the past few days or so, I have tried to find a prophecy of this sort attributed to him---without success.

Furthermore, I know that the alluded to show did do a segment on him in the 1990s, and maybe one thereafter---but from what I can find out, they may have pertained to miraculous healings.

I am certain that such a prophecy was presented on television in the 1990s; and so, I imagine, that others are familiar with it---whether by that program, or by some other means.

My question: Can someone recall more specifically, what the details of the alluded to prophecy are; and who is it attributed to? Bl. Solanus Casey? Someone else? Thank you.

Comment: Was it in [this documentary](https://www.cultureunplugged.com/play/8037/The-Healing-Prophet--Solanus-Casey/)?

Comment: @Geremia Thank you for posting this; however, I did not find the alluded to prophecy in it.

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert, but I did a little research on him for some scout activities since he's a local hero/saint.  I'd never heard that he was a prophet as well. Didn't he play his fiddle for bees?  Sounds more like a Nostradamus sort of thing.   Could we change this question to "did Bl. Solanus Casey prophecy?" or something like that, otherwise you're asking a yes or no question + what was it.  And this is a little harder to answer even than some of our classic 80's Christian mix-tape questions.

Comment: @PeterTurner A prophet is not always predicting the future; but in this regard, Bl. Solanus seemed to excel in matters pertaining to illnesses---one's recovery or not; for many examples, please view the documentary Geremia posted above as a comment. If we restrict prophecy to one who has knowledge of future events, Bl Solanus would most definitely be included in this group. As for Nostradamus, his quatrains were intentionally obscured; I am not aware of any which clearly speaks of America. If you know of one specifically (or which pertains to floods), please let me know.